# 'could not find or load main class weka.gui.GUIChooser' error

Tags: weka

while adding a new classifier in weka...by running java call :java -classpath  "weka.jar;weka-src.jar" weka.gui.GUIChooser
what to set classpath...and is it the correct format to add a classifier a weka...i am using windows
 10

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding classifiers, you are adding .jar files.

You have to use absolute paths (C:/...) to the jar files. `java -classpath "c:/.../weka.jar"`

weka-src.jar is not neeeded.

It is optional to set the working directory of your script/batch file to the directory where the weka.jar file can be found.

Comment: thanks for ur answer....but it opens the weka explorer......i want to create a new classifier which is located in weka-src.jar file

Comment: Then, actually, I don't understand what you are up to. If you want to create or add classfiers you should use the package manager which is available via the GuiChooser. That's the small rectangular dialog box with 4 buttons on the right hand side, and some menu items, one of which (under "Tools") is the package manager. Available since weka 3.7.

Comment: then can u plzz suggest me which package should i install for clonalg classifier

Comment: That's a completely different question unrelated to the title of this post, and your question text. Edit the title of this post and rewrite your question; or ask a new question with appropriate context.